# Expected resource of type id error - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got error "Expected resource of type id error" in Android Studio 2.0. 
The code is actually pretty simple. I am trying to learn intents but have got error in setContentView method. Could you please check ?

1. //code starts here

   ```
   package com.example.oksijen02.sorunmuvar;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private static final int REQUEST_CODE=10;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           //following line getting error of "expected resource of type id.."
           setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));

       }

       // here button action to define an intent and its extra value
       public void onClick(View view){
           EditText text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputforintent);
           String value = text.getText().toString();
          //Define intent
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
           //add Edit Text value to send next activity via intent
           intent.putExtra("senttext",value);

       }

   }
   ```
2. // we have our MainActivity xml here

   ```
    //Edit Text in main activity
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/inputforintent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minHeight="60dip"
       android:text="FirstActivity"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       />

   //here we have button to pass other page which its code unwritten here  
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/startIntent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputforintent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/inputforintent"
       android:onClick="onClick"
       android:text="Calling an intent"
       />
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setContentView method does not require the findViewById()method

```
 setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));
```

Change it to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```